# gitweb: Use Apache HTTP basic authentication for repository authentication

Tags: git, http-basic-authentication

I use gitweb to serve remote Git repositories on a server running Apache2. Everything is setup with automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS and Basic password authentication (though this might change to a more powerful method in the future). This works well, but I can only control access to all repositories at once using `Require group gitters` (or similar) in the `VirtualHost` definition.

A few fairly old answers here suggest to use gitolite for repository-based authentication, however this seems to be a completely different architecture with its own credential storage. Then there would be the option to put the various repositories in different directories with individual `<Location /xy>` specifiers in the Apache config.

It would be perfect if I could simply add an option to each repo.git/config file specifying which htusers/htgroups are allowed to access the repository. Does gitweb offer something like this? Maybe using the `$export_auth_hook` variable?

Thanks,
Philipp